# Issues updating Jenkins Plugins

Tags: jenkins, plugins, notifications, warnings, updates

I was on Jenkins version 2.176 using the standalone war.

I then got security vulnerability alert for plugins here: https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2020-03-09/

I then decided to update Jenkins so I downloaded and started Jenkins with the latest version: Jenkins ver. 2.224

I then updated all the plugins and took restart.

However, under monitors, I see two notifications.

The first notification says:

> "You have data stored in an older format and/or unreadable data."

[image]

The second notification says:

> "Warnings have been published for the following currently installed
>   components."
>
> Build Pipeline Plugin 1.5.8 Stored XSS vulnerability Environment
>   Injector Plugin 2.3.0 Exposure of sensitive build variables stored by
>   EnvInject 1.90 and earlier

[image]

Under the plugin update tab I don't find any plugins listed for updates !!

Can you please suggest how can I overcome both these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no new versions of the vulnerable Plugins available as of today.

[The XSS Vulnerability for the Build Pipeline Plugin is only exploitable on Jenkins releases older than 2.146 or 2.138.2](https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2019-08-07/#SECURITY-879)

For the Environment Injector Plugin Vulnerability:

> To prevent the further exposure of sensitive build variables, we
>   recommend that you take the following steps if you are affected by
>   this:
>
> - Disable the visualization of Injected Environment variables in the
>     global configuration. After this change the data will be accessible
>     only to those ones who have access to raw build.xml files. This is a
>     reversible action that can be applied immediately, and can be reverted
>     once you’ve purged the data on disk (below).
> - Remove the sensitive data
>     from disk by manually removing corresponding entries from
>     injectedEnvVars.txt files, or deleting the injectedEnvVars.txt files
>     in old build directories.
> - Rotate all secrets that have potentially
>     been exposed

from the [Security Advisory 2018-02-26](https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2018-02-26/#SECURITY-248)

Comment: @ Julian Veerkamp What are the recommendations and approach i.e solution one should take upon ending up with this problem? Any tested steps which you can recommend?

Comment: Sadly not. I would first try to get rid of the old data. 
Under Manage Jenkins you should find a "Manage old data". You can ignore unreadable Data as Jenkins will just ignore that. If there's no old Data left I would check if the Plugin Version you have installed is the same as the latest Plugin version. It seems that the unsafe plugins don't have a safe version available.